How Do I Simplify These Massive Boolean Equations?
I'm fairly new to this, and I am working on a computer that would play tic-tac-toe with you. It takes the position convert it into binary split it into different inputs, run it through some function and then combine the given inputs to create the outcome of the computer. It is chaotic, so I will give an example:
I'm working on building a computer that can play Tic-tac-toe. The idea is to have it analyze the board, process the position by converting it into binary, break it down into inputs, run these through a set of functions, and combine the outputs to create the binary representation of the computer's move. The process is a bit chaotic, so here's an example:
X O                                                                                                    X O
 X  -> b'0b001111110101111' -> A=0,B=,...O=1 -> f1-15 -> Q1=0,Q2=0,...Q15=1 -> b'0b001111111100101' ->  XO
X O                                                                                                    X O

To simplify the problem, I created a list of all legal board positions and their corresponding best moves. By converting these positions into binary, It creates a truth table where every legal input corresponds to an output.
We can write it as
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO|Q123456789012345
---------------|----------------
001111110101111| 001111111100101
000111011001111| 001111111100101
...            |...

I converted it into a function for each output using a Karnaugh map (a basic version for each cell individually, no grouping) and got enormous functions each 76'000 characters long.
Example:
!A*!B*C*!D*E*F*!G*H*I*!J*K*!L*M*!N*!O+A*!B*!C*D*!E*!F*!G*H*I*!J*K*!L*M*N*!O+!A*!B*C*!D*E*!F*!G*!H*!I*J*!K*!L*!M*!N*O+!A*B*!C*D*!E*!F*G*H*!I*J*!K*L*!M*N*!O...

I know the functions can be simplified, but due to their size, I haven't been able to do it manually or with equation-simplifying tools—most tools can't handle the large equations.
Does anyone have advice on how to approach simplifying these large functions or any tools that could help?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Put a table in memory.  Use the input words as the address, and program the memory locations with the output word.
Done.
